# How to make LVI stretch to width of its container?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to get my ListView control to look real nice, but I can't get the ListViewItem to stretch to the full width of the ListView control.

I've seen it in many apps on the store. But I just can't get it:

[image]

I am beginning to think that maybe the apps that look like it is stretched are not actually using ListViews, but some other kind of List.

How do I make the Item stretch to the width of its container?

Below is what I am using:

```
            <ListView x:Name="list" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0, 37, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Note}" Width="376" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="Magenta" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="376">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionHighlightColor="#FF4617B4" />
                            <!--<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Jan 20, 2013" FontSize="9" Foreground="#FF4E7189" HorizontalAlignment="Right" SelectionHighlightColor="#FF9BCAEC" />-->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple options. For whatever reason they have it set in the template so if you check out the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709921.aspx) you'll see the `Margin="0,0,18,2"` (also other odd margins on multiple objects stacking up for that matter) so if you really wanted to fix it, you could expose the default template and fix it directly, or make a copy of your own an apply directly, or for a quickie try just adding;

```
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That `18` in there is for _right_, so I think that 18 pixels is space left for the Vertical scrollbar. Thanks so much for this @Chris :)